# Empty response content using symfony http client

Tags: php, api, symfony, request

I have got trouble fetching the content of error responses (400/500) when using Symfony http client (RetryableHttpClient) and AsyncResponse:

The content is always empty, no matter if I do `getContent()` within a try/catch statement or use `getContent(false)` (`false`=dont throw an exception on error status code). The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) states that `getContent()` will wait for the whole response to be fetched, even when using streamed/async Responses.

If I test the same request i.e. via Postman the response content is a json, as expected.

**Example V1:**

```
/* @var Symfony\Component\HttpClient\RetryableHttpClient $client */
$response = $client->request('POST', '/something' , [
    'auth_bearer' => '******',
    'body' => [
        "some" => "thing"
    ]
]);

/* @var Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Response\AsyncResponse $response */
p_r($response->getContent(false)); // empty
```

**Example V2 (try/catch):**

```
try {
    ... see V1
    $response->getContent(); // throws exception
} catch (ClientExceptionInterface|ServerExceptionInterface $exception) {
    p_r($exception->getResponse()->getContent(false)); // empty
}
```

Comment: Hello, have you try to dd($response); ?

Comment: I noticed with Postman is working, Postman add dynamic headers, like "Content-Type application/json". Could you try to add in your client request.

Answer (score 0):

can you trying the toArray ? in the documentation for payload Json it is better to get the toArray [link](https://github.com/symfony/http-client-contracts/blob/c5f587eb445224ddfeb05b5ee703476742d730bf/ResponseInterface.php#L62)

```
$exception->getResponse()->toArray(false)
```

Comment: I get `JsonException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
Response body is empty.` Furthermore, I am using deserializers for the response content, so toArray() would break my logic anyways ...